# Z(G)<C(a)<=G why is this true?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can anybody provide a proof of this? Also is it true that for an arbitrary y in G, but not in Z(G) that we obtain Z(G)< C(a) < G? (Note: C(a) is the centralizer and Z(G) is the center).

Answer (score 1):

Write down the definitions:

$$Z(G)=\{h\in G: hg=gh\},$$

$$C(a)=\{h\in G: ha=ah\}.$$

Note that $$Z(G)=\cap_{a\in G}C(a)$$ and thus $Z(G)\subset C(a).$

In other words, any element in $Z(G)$ commute with any other element in $G.$ In particular, commute with $a,$ and thus $Z(G)\subset C(a).$

Comment: That is what I initially thought. Does this in essence also prove that Z(G) is never maximal?@mfl

Comment: Note that we can have $Z(G)=C(a)$ or $C(a)=G.$

Comment: Is it possible in general then to have Z(G)<C(a)<G? @ mfl

Comment: Here you have an example http://www.math.niu.edu/~beachy/abstract_algebra/study_guide/soln32.html#s3232